# Convert Maver Project to "normal" Java Application project in Netbeans

Tags: java, maven, netbeans

This is my problem: I'm new at Java, I started a Maven project because I needed to use a lib that requierd that. Then I no longer needed it but keep going with the Maven project. Now I'm trying to build it but the .jar does not run the project when double clicked.
Since I don't know Maven very well (I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26040366/jar-files-created-with-maven-do-not-open) but didn't understand it), I thought that the easiest way was to convert the proyect into a "normal" Java App project. So I copied all files with classes from the Maven project folder to a new Java App project folder manually.
It opens fine, but I got this error when retrieving an ArrayList:

`Exception in thread "pool-1-thread-5" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList cannot be cast to java.util.ArrayList`

Since this doesn't happen in the Maven project I assume that it happens due to my archaic method to copy the classes...

**So,** is there a way to convert my Maven Project into a normal Java Project? I have found a lot of topics about doing the opposite but anything useful about what I need (only [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26588439/how-to-convert-back-maven-project-to-java-web-project) but it is not what I need).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try closing the project on NetBeans and importing a project from existing file system.

However I feel that is not the ideal way to do it, but it should allow you to run it as you require.
Disabling the Maven nature is also viable.

According to [Java Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassCastException.html), java.lang.ClassCastException is
thrown to indicate that the code has attempted to cast an Object to a subclass of which it is not an instance.

There might be a chance that you are getting that exception cause you are missing some library or class which implements the same interface or allows you to convert the object to a given type.